# Starting multiquery in client throws parser error

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I have a following problem in c# SDK: when I try to run multiquery in my desktop application with following string (searching for pairs of IDs of mutual friends) I get a parser error:

```
string strCommonFriendsQuery = "{
        \"user_friends\":\"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()\", 
        \"mutual_friends\":\"SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM   #user_friends) AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #user_friends)\"
        }";

        fb.Query(strCommonFriendsQuery);
```

*Parser error: unexpected '{' at position 0.*

The same string (without the escape sequences before quotation marks) works if I paste it to 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/
but not in
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/
so the problem is that I need to launch it as multiquery and not as a query - now what I would like to ask is:

**Is it possible to somehow process multi-query using the *Facebook.FacebookClient.Query* function of the SDK or do I have to write a function which would do that? As I understand the only thing I would need to change is the address to which it connects to. If so, could it be added in the next SDK version?**

Comment: I feel really stupid not finding out that the function has two prototypes where the other one takes an array of strings for multiquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a multiquery with a reference to the first query, such as the one in the question, do as follows:

```
//note: queries begin from 0, not from 1
string query0 = "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()";
string query1 = "SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query0) AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query0)";

dynamic result = fb.Query(query0, query1);
```

To answer this, I got inspired from here (had to figure out that queries start from 0): [How to use fql.multiquery with C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802037/how-to-use-fql-multiquery-with-c-sdk)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm glad to see a solution.  However, this seems a bit too magical for my tastes.  How did the variable names end up being conveyed as query names?  IOW, what is the non-dynamic version of this?  To reflector...

Comment: Ahh, query<n> is simply the auto-naming convention used in Query(). Items are added from the provided list as such: dictionary.Add("query" + i, fql[i]);  The result is passed to Get().

Comment: Yeah, I named the strings "query0" and "query1" to avoid confusion. I could have named them also "foo" and "bar" if I wanted, but still they would be called "query0" and "query1" without specifying their name as you did in your following answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate to firepol's answer, with named queries:

```
var queries = 
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "FamDamly", "select uid from family where profile_id = me()" },
        { "FamDetails", "select uid, first_name from user where uid in #FamDamly" }
    };
client.Get(queries);
```

Comment: cool, didn't know it was possible to name the queries, thanks for that.