# how to login facebook and get the online friends in the new facebook SDK (5.0.9) (C#)

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

i could realy use some help here,
how can i make a simple facebook connection and get the online friends with the new facebook sdk for C#?
10Q.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an FQL multiquery

query0, select all friends
query1, select all online friends , from query0.

```
var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic result = fb.Query(query0, query1);
```

See example in my other answer here:

[Starting multiquery in client throws parser error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144488/starting-multiquery-in-client-throws-parser-error/5854145#5854145)

Check also this other question: [How to get list of online friends using FQL with facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api)

And these:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/

Remember to grant the proper permissions to access that information, which I think are **"friends_about_me"** in this case.

Check also here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Hope this helps